# Mocha is not retrying if failure occurs in before() or beforeEach() hooks?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, automation, mocha.js

I have defined retires as 3 in `.mocharc.json` file

```
{
    "retries": 3
}
```

My spec file is

```
const chai = require('chai');
const dirtyChai = require('dirty-chai');

const { expect } = chai;


chai.use(dirtyChai);

describe('Database Connection', () => {
  before(() => {
    expect(false).to.be.true();
    console.log('My Before Block');
  });
  it('Local connection', async () => {
    console.log('My Test Block');
  });
});
```

My expectation is, it should run for three times, as the `before` block will fail in the above code. But, i see the execution is happening only once.

if the failure occurs in `it` block, then the execution is happening 3 times.

Can someone explain what the issue is? I want the code to run 3 times even if there is a failure in before() or beforeEach() block.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that you can do is wrap your beforeEach() script in try/catch block. It would not error out then.